# iframe domain issues leading to 500 internal server error

Tags: iframe

I have a strange issue with a website that cannot reference any resources from another site.

The source site (A) is trying to iframe a page from the other site (B).  For some reason, site (B) is returning a 500 internal server error.

I then tried just to reference a simple image from site (B) with a  tag and that returned a 404.

It's obviously something server related but I'm not sure what it could be.  The iframe to server (B) works fine if it's used on any other site.  So there is some cross-domain like issue going on when server (A) tries to contact server (B).

To make things more complicated, using "curl" from server (A) to access server (B) works fine.

Anyone encountered something like this before?

Thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error could either be a circular dependency or a blacklisted server. The 404 implies the latter.

Do you control both servers? Or is B owned by someone else who might have blocked the IP of server A?

If the latter, play nicely and send the owner of server B an email. If the former, check that you've not accidentally configured apache to block any IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

It's the former, and actually is related to one server migrating over apps (from A to B) and I believe some DNS server config settings not being removed.  

e.g. - we were able to remove one setting that changed the 500 to a 404 completely.  I'll look into the blocked server part.

Thanks